# How to disable defaults.vim?

Tags: default-settings

On my system vim has a "defaults.vim" file that is getting sourced. For example, if I do vim --version, I see the following:

```
   system vimrc file: "$VIM/vimrc"
     user vimrc file: "$HOME/.vimrc"
 2nd user vimrc file: "~/.vim/vimrc"
      user exrc file: "$HOME/.exrc"
       defaults file: "$VIMRUNTIME/defaults.vim"
```

The problem is that the defaults file has a bunch of annoying settings in it. How can I disable it? I had read elsewhere that as long as I had a ~/.vimrc file that the defaults file would not be loaded, but this is not true. I have a blank ~/.vimrc and defaults is still getting loaded. How can I prevent this?

Comment: Why do you have a blank .vimrc, and not one with your preferred settings?

Comment: @HerbWolfe Because I am just using this server for 15 minutes. I do not want invest an afternoon in it. I just want the default settings OFF NOW.

Comment: Are you certain the defaults aren't off?  `:version` reports those files regardless of anything, it does not necessarily mean they're being loaded.

Comment: This question could be improved if you told us 1) which default options you find annoying and 2) what result you do want as opposed to what you do *not* want. Please also share the output of `:scriptnames`.

Answer (score 3):

From `:h defaults.vim`:

> If Vim is started normally and no user vimrc file is found, the
>   $VIMRUTIME/defaults.vim script is loaded.

Perhaps an empty vimrc is the same as no vimrc...? Anyways, try this...

Near the start of `$VIMRUNTIME/defaults.vim` you'll see:

```
if exists('skip_defaults_vim')
  finish
endif
```

So put something like this near the start of your *system* vimrc and that should suppress it:

```
let skip_defaults_vim=1
```

Use of this variable in the system vimrc is documented: `:h skip_defaults_vim`

Comment: On my machines, I use `let g:skip_defaults_vim = 1` in `/etc/vim/vimrc.local` and can confirm that it does work.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following command to start Vim without loading any initialization files.

Note the command is case-sensitive.

```
vim -u NONE -N
```

- `-u NONE` prevents the loading of initialization files.
- `-N` explicitly turns off Vi compatibility. This makes Vim behave normally.

You can test the result in Vim by using the `:scriptnames` command to show that no script files were loaded. (There should be no output, and Vim will return to Normal mode.)

- [-u | starting.txt | VimHelp.org](https://vimhelp.org/starting.txt.html#-u)
- [-N | starting.txt | VimHelp.org](https://vimhelp.org/starting.txt.html#-N)
- [:scriptnames | VimHelp.org](https://vimhelp.org/repeat.txt.html#%3Ascriptnames)
- [compatible-default | VimHelp.org](https://vimhelp.org/starting.txt.html#compatible-default)

---

Note that you have to type these options each time you run Vim.

If you are working in a terminal and are willing to modify your shell then you can create an *alias* for Vim where these options are automatically included each time Vim is run.

For example:

```
alias myvim="vim -u NONE -N"

myvim /home/user/some_file.txt
```

By using a unique alias like `myvim`, you can avoid a name collision with an existing application or alias.

- [How to Create Bash Aliases | Linuxize](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-create-bash-aliases/)
- [Vim Aliases | VimHelp.org](https://vimhelp.org/starting.txt.html#ex)
- [PowerShell Example | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/new-alias#examples)

Comment: Welcome to Vi and Vim SE. Note that `vim --clean` *will* source `defaults.vim`. You can see by running `:scriptnames`. Since OP isn't particularly clear about what he wants, this is as good an answer as any.

Comment: Correct, if you want to disable loading `defaults.vim`, use `vim -u NONE -N`